# Macro to Set Range value based on a variable

Tags: excel, vba

Hi'm new to VBA and i'm trying to work on a QA report(call audit) that will automatically calculate values based on the data of another worksheet. I have 2 Sheets: Elements which contains the data, and AutoMacro which shows the number of cells that meets a specific criteria.

The Elements sheet has columns named Element and Rate, and WeekNumber. I made a code that will list all distinct week numbers to the "AM" column of the Automacro Sheet. Now, i want to count how many calls got a rate of 'Developing'(which is in column Rate of the Elements sheet) in Compassion(which is in column Element of the Elements sheet) on a specific week(AM column in the AutoMacro Sheet)

this code works fine:

```
CompDevCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
    Sheets("Elements").Range("f2:F1048576"), "Compassion", _
    Sheets("Elements").Range("G2:G1048576"),"Developing", _
    Sheets("Elements").Range("C2:C1048576"), "4")
```

however, instead of putting a fixed value in the last criterion which is the weeknumber, i want my code to get the value of the corresponding cell in column AM(if macro is calculating values for row2 in the AutoMacro sheet, it should change the "4" to whatever value AM2 has) and i cant figure out how to do it.

any help is greatly appreciated

here's a link to my sample file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZXuMsQv_mzvycPXnGCGY7bUL6-gWBrBr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where in your code is the `row2` value assigned?

Comment: The question should be able to stand on its own.  Many will not download a macro enabled workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code bellow:

```
Sub LetsCount()

Dim lastElementsRowIndex As Long
Dim wsElements As Worksheet
Dim wsAutoMacro As Worksheet
Dim elementRange As Range
Dim rateRange As Range
Dim weekRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim weekNumber As Integer

Set wsElements = Sheets("Elements")
Set wsAutoMacro = Sheets("AutoMacro")

'//Get the index of the last filled row based on column A (Analyst)
lastElementsRowIndex = wsElements.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'//Get ranges
Set elementRange = wsElements.Range("F2:F" & lastElementsRowIndex)
Set rateRange = wsElements.Range("G2:G" & lastElementsRowIndex)
Set weekRange = wsElements.Range("C2:C" & lastElementsRowIndex)

'//Looping through all filled rows in the AutoMacro sheet
For i = 2 To wsAutoMacro.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '//Get week number from cell in column "AM"
    weekNumber = wsAutoMacro.Cells(i, "AM").Value

    '//Get the number of calls with: Rate = 'Developing', Element = 'Compassion' and Week Number = weekNumber
    CompDevCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
    elementRange, "Compassion", _
    rateRange, "Developing", _
    weekRange, weekNumber)

    '//Insert the value in the corresponding cell of the AN column (column that I adopted to put the value)
    wsAutoMacro.Cells(i, "AN").Value = CompDevCount
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you are 'Heaven sent' @Hudson Assis. your code did what i exactly wanted. Gosh, this is my first time posting a question here and i didnt expect i'd get a response this quick. I'm not even sure how to tag you here. LOL. thank you again :)

Comment: i have another question @user:8238866 sorry. I'm assuming you checked my file because i see you mentioned the Analyst column in your code. Aside from 'Developing', the Rate column of the Elements sheet also has cells with 'Meeting' and 'Exceeding' values in them; the Element column on the other hand has cells with 4 other values aside from 'Compassion' in them. I am looking to also count the cells that meet the below criteria:

Compassion - Meeting
Compassion - Exceeding 
acknowledgement - Meeting... and so on

Comment: ive tried changing the criterion for element and rate and it works fine but this would mean ill have to make 14 sets of countifs inside the For Loop. im wondering if there's an easier and shorter way to do it. Appreciate your help..

Comment: Hey @KarenDP, I uploaded an Excel file in this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OaQzrDv3up2-0dndN0Bz_ibFwl_GsDU2/view?usp=sharing. I used formulas to get what you want. It's a different approach to VBA, maybe it might be interesting for you.

Comment: it is interesting indeed. i just went ahead and made 14 sets of For loops. I'm sure i'd be able to use your 2nd suggestion in the future. thank you again